# Resize a video object in Flash Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I made a working AS3 code in flash to display and play a progressive video. I'm using javascript to dynamically embed it in a page with specified width and height. The embeded object's with and height is correct but the video content becomes larger than the size of its container. So how do I resize video in AS3 to match it's container object when it's embeded in html?

AS3 Code:

```
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var nc, ns, vd, st;
var isLoaded = false;
var isPlaying = false;
var vW = ExternalInterface.call('video.w');
var vH = ExternalInterface.call('video.h');

function video(w,h){
    nc = new NetConnection(); nc.connect(null);
    ns = new NetStream(nc);
    vd = new Video(w,h);

    ns.client = this;
    vd.attachNetStream(ns);
    stage.addChild(vd);
}

function playpause(e){
    if(isLoaded == false){
        ns.play('http://localhost.com/project/vid/sample_1.mp4');
        isLoaded = true;
        isPlaying = true;
    }
    else{
        if(isPlaying == false){
            ns.resume();
            isPlaying = true;
        }
        else{
            ns.pause();
            isPlaying = false;
        }
    }
}
video(vW,vH);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playpause);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>video</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script>
            function player(container,w,h){
                var container = document.getElementById(container);
                var flashHTML = '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="video.swf" width="'+w+'" height="'+h+'"><param name="movie" value="video.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#cccccc" /><param name="play" value="true" /><param name="loop" value="true" /><param name="wmode" value="window" /><param name="menu" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></object>';

                container.innerHTML = flashHTML;

                this.w = function(){return w}
                this.h = function(){return h}
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="flashContent"></div>
        <script>
            var video = new player('flashContent',853,480);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call video.w and video.h as functions so they return a value.

```
var vW = ExternalInterface.call('video.w()');
var vH = ExternalInterface.call('video.h()');
```

should work

Comment: Dan this is not the correct answer as brackets do not matter in this case.

Comment: I just figured out the answer after few hours of tracing. I had a stage with dimension of '640 x 360' same as the video. Problem happens if I dynamically resize the video larger than the stage. After applying new dimension change, the video expanded to '853 x 480' while stage remains at '640 x 360' as the original. Setting the scaleMode of stage and repositioning solved the video display problem. >> stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

Comment: @Gio Just curious, My console in Chrome will return the function itself if I run it without ()'s after it. Is this a chrome only behavior? Michael, glad you figured it out. I had a similar problem before with the stage scale settings, sorry I didn't think of that sooner.

Comment: @dan2600 No it's not Chrome only behaviour. When you call a function from the Chrome/Firefox or any other console, you just run Javascript from there, that's why brackets are needed. But when calling from Flash `ExternalInterface.call()` method handles it automatically, so only passing the function name works.